# Поиск дублирующих элементов в коллекции JS

Tags: javascript, коллекции, filter, lodash

```
var collections = [
 { level: 1, text: 'text' },
 { level: 2, text: 'text2' },
 { level: 1, text: 'text3' },
 { level: 3, text: 'text4' },
 { level: 4, text: 'text5' },
 { level: 3, text: 'text6' },
]

var newCollections = funcFilter(collections, 'level')

newCollections #=> [{ level: 1, text: 'text' }, { level: 1, text: 'text3' }, { level: 3, text: 'text4' }, { level: 3, text: 'text6' }]
```

Здравствуйте.
Как вытащить из коллекции элементы которые не являются уникальными (повторяются два и более раз) по указанному полю (в данном случае level)?
Если можно, то с использованием lodash, если там есть похожий метод (сам не смог найти).

Answer (score 1):

```
const res = _.chain(collections)
    .groupBy('level') // группируем по level
    .values() // берем только массивы соответствующие level 
    .filter(arrs => _.size(arrs) > 1) // берем те массивы, в которых элементов больше 1 (не уникальные)
    .flatten() // выпрямляем массив
    .value();
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось вот так. Все работает, но что-то мне подсказывает, что должно быть решение изящнее. Может это натолкнет на мысль.

```js
var collections = [{
    level: 1,
    text: 'text'
  },
  {
    level: 2,
    text: 'text2'
  },
  {
    level: 1,
    text: 'text3'
  },
  {
    level: 3,
    text: 'text4'
  },
  {
    level: 4,
    text: 'text5'
  },
  {
    level: 3,
    text: 'text6'
  },
];

function funcFilter(collect) {

  var uniqueRes = [];
  var duplicateRes = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < collect.length; i++) {

    var obj = collect[i];

    var level = obj.level;

    for (var j = 0; j < uniqueRes.length; j++) {

      var dubble = uniqueRes[j]

      var resLevel = dubble.level;

      if (resLevel === level) {

        duplicateRes.push(dubble);
         duplicateRes.push(obj);

      }

    }

    uniqueRes.push(obj);

  }
  
  return duplicateRes

};

var newCollections = funcFilter(collections);

console.log(newCollections);
```

Answer (score 0):

Сам отвечаю на свой вопрос =)
Получилось такое решение с lodash. При этом не нарушается последовательность коллекции. И при коллекции в 3000 элементов работает относительно шустро.

```
function funcFilter(collect, field) {
  const countBy   = _.countBy(collect, function(o) { return o[field]; });
  const pickBy    = _.pickBy(countBy, function(o) { return o > 1; });
  const keys      = _.keys(pickBy);
  const duplicate = _.filter(collect, function(o) { return _.includes(keys, o[field]); });
  return duplicate;
}
```