# Нахождение повторяющихся последовательностей в массивах

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Дано множество массивов примерно с таким содержимым:

```
[
  [D6],
  [D5],
  [D5, D6],
  [D3, D6],
  [D4],
  [D4, D6],
  [D4, D5],
  [D4, D5, D6]
  ...
]
```

Необходимо найти все повторяющиеся последовательности (больше 2х элементов) из этих массивов. Для примера выше:

```
[
  [D6],
  [D5],
  [D5, D6],
  [D3, D6],
  [D4],
  [D4, D6],
  [T1],
  [T1, D6]
  ...
]
```

Два последних массива содержат в себе подмножество [D4, D5] => меняем во всех массивах где встречается подмножество [D4, D5] на T1.

Первое что приходит на ум это сгенерировать все возможные комбинации из элементов этих массивов и потом проходится по массивам и искать вхождения, но помоему это не совсем лучшее решение, как решить эту задачу более оптимально?

**UPD:**
Второе что приходит в голову искать пересечения массивов но придется перебрать каждый с каждым, но мне кажется что существует более оптимальное решение

Comment: [D4, D5] на T1 у вас в примере говорится больше двух элементов, а тут два, а два не больше двух. Или вы имеете ввиду больше либо равно двум?

Comment: Так же непонятно что такое повторяющиеся последовательности. Это где полное совпадение ннапример A B C, A B C, или A B C , A B тоже повторяющееся, или A B C, A C тоже повторяющееся? A B C D, B C повторяющийся?

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/746649/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-js

Comment: Больше либо равно 2. Повторяющиеся = пересечению множеств.
A,B,C и A,C пересекаются (повторяющиеся)

Comment: Можно делать не все подмножества а только подмножества из двух частей, а потом как в вашем вопросе заменять на Z1, Z2 таким образом будет рекурсия. И если есть из трёх элементов, он уже будет. Но тут есть одна проблема, и она же есть в условии, дело в том что скажем есть А B C и есть A B С Z и A B T, если мы заменим ABC на T1 то ABT с повторяющимся A B уже не найдём. Это не ответ, это размышляю, так как алгоритм не простой, тут надо вместе думать. То есть при замене могут некоторые повторения потеряться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так сделать. Идти по каждой строчке, и в отдельный массив `AllVariants` выписывать все последовательности из этой строчки. Это будет общий массив для всех строк. Как только в этом общем массиве мы встречаем повторение, то значит обнаружили повторение. Для ускорения работы ключём в этом большом массиве должена служить строка из отсортированых по порядку значений пример ACD. А в значение можно записывать список ссылок на тот эллемент где данное значение используется, тогда можно будет быстро и легко сделать замену.

Остаётся проблема которую я в комментарии описал. В одной последовательности, например A B C D может быть несколько повторяющихся элементов с другими последовательностями, например A D и A C, и если делать замену как в условии задачи, например мы заменим A D на T1 тогда повторение A C мы никогда уже не найдём, так как A больше нету. Но это вопрос не к решению а к условию задачи.